# Using R/dplyr to filter columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a simple Q... I have a dataset I need to filter by certain parameters. I was hoping for a solution in R?

Dummy case:

```html
colour  age animal
red     10  dog
yellow  5   cat
pink    6   cat
```

I want to classify this dataset e.g. by:

If colour is 'red' OR 'pink' AND age is <7 AND animal is 'cat' then = category 1.
Else category 2.

Output would be:

```html
colour  age animal category
red     10  dog      2
yellow  5   cat      2
pink    6   cat      1
```

Is there a way to manipulate dplyr to achieve this? I'm a clinician not a bioinformatician so go easy!

Comment: you could use `mydata %>% mutate(category=ifelse((colour=='red'|colour=='pink')&age<7 & animal=='cat',1,2))`

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the `case_when` function in dplyr to set up more complex selections with mutate.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(colour = c("red", "yellow", "pink", "red", "pink"),
              age = c(10, 5, 6, 12, 10),
              animal = c("dog", "cat", "cat", "hamster", "cat"))
df
#>   colour age  animal
#> 1    red  10     dog
#> 2 yellow   5     cat
#> 3   pink   6     cat
#> 4    red  12 hamster
#> 5   pink  10     cat

df <- mutate(df, category = case_when( 
        ((colour == "red" | colour == "pink") & age < 7 & animal == "cat") ~ 1,
         (colour == "yellow" | age != 5 & animal == "dog")                 ~ 2,
         (colour == "pink" | animal == "cat")                              ~ 3,
         (TRUE)                                                            ~ 4) )
df
#>   colour age  animal category
#> 1    red  10     dog        2
#> 2 yellow   5     cat        2
#> 3   pink   6     cat        1
#> 4    red  12 hamster        4
#> 5   pink  10     cat        3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is absolutely perfect as it'll be super helpful for much more complex classification, which is ultimately my goal. Thanks so much!

Comment: Apologies to ask another Q, but I wonder if it's possible to use the mutate function if for example you needed to classify based on:

Classify as category 1: if 2 of the following are present:

Colour = red or pink;
Age <7;
Animal is hamster;

Or is that pushing it too far?!

Comment: You can use `sum` to count the conditionals that are true. So if you want all young, red or pink hamsters to have category five you insert: `(sum( (colour == "red" | colour == "pink"), age < 7, animal == "hamster") >= 2) ~5`

Comment: you are a beauty! Thank you so much. It works!

Answer (score 1):

You could also manipulate this as :

```
df$category <- with(df,!(colour %in% c('red', 'pink') & age < 7 & animal == 'cat')) + 1
df

#  colour age animal category
#1    red  10    dog        2
#2 yellow   5    cat        2
#3   pink   6    cat        1
```

And in `dplyr` :

```
df %>%
  mutate(category = as.integer(!(colour %in% c('red', 'pink') & 
                                 age < 7 & animal == 'cat')) + 1)
```